# how to turn off (disable) jdk.event.security logs?

Tags: java, security, gradle, logging, java-11

I use spring boot application, jdk version is openjdk 11.Debug level is active in properties file. I don't know it why show jdk.event.security logs. I want to turn off that logs.

```
 DEBUG 11007 --- [main] jdk.event.security: X509Certificate: Alg:SHA1withRSA, Serial:23456, Subject:CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US, Issuer:CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US, Key type:RSA, Length:2048, Cert Id:-2028617374, Valid from:5/21/02, 9:00 AM, Valid until:5/21/22, 8:00 AM
DEBUG 11007 --- [main] jdk.event.security: X509Certificate: Alg:SHA1withRSA, Serial:bb401c43f55e4fb0, Subject:CN=SwissSign Gold CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH, Issuer:CN=SwissSign Gold CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH, Key type:RSA, Length:4096, Cert Id:1516221943, Valid from:10/25/06, 1:30 PM, Valid until:10/25/36, 12:30 PM
......

 DEBUG 11007 --- [main] jdk.event.security: X509Certificate: Alg:SHA256withRSA, Serial:4a538c28, Subject:CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Issuer:CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US, Key type:RSA, Length:2048, Cert Id:1936920337, Valid from:7/7/09, 10:25 PM, Valid until:12/7/30, 9:55 PM
```

VM options :

[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Rasul - What are your VM args related to logging as you run your application?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, I edited the question. Excuse me, my english is not good, that is why, I didn't explain well.

Comment: @Naman, I added a picture of VM options to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this line `<logger name="jdk.event.security" level="WARN"/>` in logback-spring.xml file. it will just show me warning message.